# ImageMagick: Getting Date and Time in C#?

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I am writing a C# shell application that uses ImageMagick. I want to get the EXIF `DateTimeOriginal` field, so that I can parse and reformat the date and time to timestamp a JPEG. What's the best way to do that?

Some additional information: I am using the .NET `Process` class to drive ImageMagick, and I can redirect ImageMagick's output using the output stream of the `Process` class. What I can't figure out is how to invoke ImageMagick to return the DateTimeOriginal data.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to read that kind Exif data using the objects from the .NET Framework, most notable using the `Image` class and the `TryGetPropertyItem` method.

This way you do not need to spawn a new process.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-format` commandline param and the respective options to get `DateTimeOriginal` like this `identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]"`

see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

You can do that kind of stuff with .NET built-in classes `Image` too - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you set `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true` you can just read the process's output with something like `output = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();`. If you execute `identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTimeOriginal]"` as your part of your command line, you will get the data in your `output` string.

Comment: This answer included the Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() info, which I think would help other users. So, I selected this answer as the best.